Creating many hard links to a single file gradually slows down hard link creation
I've written a backup script in Python that uses hard links to create full backups while saving a lot of space. When a new backup is made, the most recent backup is compared to the source files. If a source file has not changed (as determined by the file size and the modification time) since the last backup, a hard link to the most recent backup is made instead of copying the source file (think rsync with --link-dest=$previous_backup or Time Machine on macOS). This saves a lot of space since most of my files never change (e.g., photos, music, videos, downloaded emails).
After the eighth backup where most files are hard-linked, the backups gradually take longer and longer. See the plot below, where the x-axis is the number of backups after the first one (hence, the number of hard links for most files), and the y-axis is the number of minutes to complete the backup. The size of the backups are about 350 GB in 166,000 files.

If I force a backup to copy all files without creating hard links, then all subsequent backups are fast once again. But, the time taken once again gradually increases after the 9th or 10th backup.
Is this behavior inherent to hard links or the NTFS file system? Is there some way to work around it?
Some relevant writings found through googling:

Post discussing similar behavior observed with some guesses as to the cause in the replies
Microsoft engineer discusses the general architecture of NTFS and how it relates to system calls


I would use fsutil.exe and some test scripts to replicate a similar scenario where multiple hard-links are created. The n you can check if the behavior is the same (thus the problem is Windows or NTFS).
